# I want to read a json file and want to read each individual object separately

Tags: python, json, dictionary

This is how the JSON looks like:

```
{
"event_id": 1,
"des": "State ID:*",
"des1": "job failure",
"event_type": "now",
"parm_ds": {
      "sup": {},
      "steps": {
       "9": {},
       "10": {},
       "2": {}
},
       "event_parms": {}
},
"event_id": 2,
"des": "State ID:2*",
"des1": "job failure1",
"event_type": "now2",
"parm_ds": {
      "sup": {},
      "steps": {
      "9": {},
      "10": {},
      "2": {}
},
      "event_parms": {}
```

}
}

I want to insert these details back into the database , so I want to take each json object and extract details from each object and input it back into the database with columns event_id, des, des1, event_type and parm_ds. Please suggest how I can do this.

In this case :

```
{
 "event_id": 1,
 "des": "State ID:*",
 "des1": "job failure",
 "event_type": "now",
 "parm_ds": {
  "sup": {},
  "steps": {
   "9": {},
   "10": {},
   "2": {}
},
   "event_parms": {}
}
```

is a single JSON object

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. Do you have an array of objects, or a stream of objects (comma separated or just juxtaposed).

Comment: {
  "event_id": 1,
  "des": "State ID:*",
  "des": "job failure",
  "event_type": "now",
  "parm_ds": {
      "sup": {},
      "steps": {
        "9": {},
        "10": {},
        "2": {}
    },
      "event_parms": {}
  },
   "event_id": 2,
  "des": "State ID:2*",
  "des": "job failure1",
  "event_type": "now2",
  "parm_ds": {
      "sup": {},
      "steps": {
        "9": {},
        "10": {},
        "2": {}
    },
      "event_parms": {}
  }
}

@chepner this is my JSON